# set transaction isolation level repeatable read is giving dead locks

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am updating some records in session 1 with open transaction -

```
begin transaction
update aa
set name = 'harry1'
where name = 'harry'
```

As you can see that commit/rollback transaction is not issued. Now i try to read the records from another session session 2.

```
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
select * from aa
```

Now Isolation level - repeatable read should give me the same old value that was there before update statement in session 1 that should be harry and not harry1.. please correct me if i am wrong.
But when I try to read record in session 2 while transaction is still  open in session 1 I get deadlock..can someone tell me why repeatable read is not working and is behaving like read committed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPEATABLE READ is same as READ COMMITTED but in addition share locks are retained on rows read for the duration of the transaction.  In other words any row that is read cannot be modified by another connection until the transaction commits or rolls back.

So your query on the session 2 is waiting for either commit or rollback on the session 1.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I get it now finally. I was trying to figure out since long what am I missing.

Comment: read commit: if another transaction tries to access the data while in an transaction block it will have to wait until a commit has occurred.   Select, insert, delete, and update are block using a read committed until the begin tran process has committed.   READ COMMITTED prevents dirty read.  REPEATABLE READ prevents non-repeatable reads

Answer (score 0):

while data is being read in the begin tran block, no other transactions are allow update, preventing a dirty read.   Therefore a non-repeatable read does not occur.  Once the commit has occurred that an update to the customer table is allow by a concurrent process.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

BEGIN TRAN
      --first read
      SELECT first_name, last_name from customer WHERE customer_id=5
      ---second read
      SELECT first_name, last_name from customer WHERE customer_id=5
COMMIT TRAN
```